# Distributing data on cluster (using torrents?)

Tags: cluster-computing, file-transfer, bittorrent

I hope this is a good place to ask this, otherwise please redirect me to the correct forum.
I have a large amount of data (~400GB) I need to distribute to all nodes in a cluster (~100 nodes). Any help into how to do this will be appreciated, following here is what Ive tried.
I was thinking of doing this using torrents but I'm running into a bunch of issues. These are the steps I tried:

1. I downloaded ctorrent to create the torrent and seed and download it. I had a problem because I didn't have a tracker.
2. I found that qbittorrent-nox has an embedded tracker so I downloaded that on one of my nodes and set the tracker up.
3. I now created the torrent using the tracker I created and copied it to my nodes.
4. When I run the torrent with ctorrent on the node with the actual data on it to seed the data I get:

   ```
    Seed for others 72 hours
    - 0/0/1 [1/1/1] 0MB,0MB | 0,0K/s | 0,0K E:0,1 Connecting
   ```
5. When I run on one of the nodes to download the data I get:

   ```
    - 0/0/1 [0/1/0] 0MB,0MB | 0,0K/s | 0,0K E:0,1
   ```
6. So it seems they aren't connecting to the tracker ok, but I don't know why

I am probably doing something very wrong, but I can't figure it out.
If anyone can help me with what I am doing, or has any way of distributing the data efficiently, even not with torrents, I would be very happy to hear.

Thanks in advance for any help available.

Comment: If the cluster nodes are within the same lan you don't need a tracker at all, just a client that supports [LSD](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0014.html). As for connection problems, there's not sufficient information in your question, so all we could provide would be speculation.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/lg/murder It's a solution for Large scale server deploys using BitTorrent developed by Twitter Video: https://vimeo.com/11280885

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies!
the8472 - How can I check if the client wit h the file supports LSD, and if it does how do I run it? Other than explanations on what the protocol was I couldn't find any explanations on google of how to use it, and couldn't find references to it within ctorrent. And I couldn't understand if when I create the torrent I put the LSD IP in place of the tracker URL?

Comment: Encombe - I looked at murder earlier as well but it seemed to be a bit overcomplicated for me as I have never used Capistrano before and I find myself going into a rabbit hole, but I will try again.

Comment: *LSD*  is everywhere else known as **LPD** - **L**ocal **P**eer **D**iscovery. Also be aware that the bittorrent protocol was not designed with privacy in mind at all, so you need to be very precocious if you need to keep your data private.

Comment: *"How can I check if the client wit h the file supports LSD"* - check documentation if the clients support it and have it enabled in their configuration as a peer source. If all involved clients do then it should work automatically on a local network.

Comment: qbittorent has LDP enabled. I am testing with 2 nodes, 1 with the file, and I create the torrent with ctorrent as mentioned. ctorrent is forcing me to give a tracker, so I do. Then using qbittorent I try to share but the node thats supposed to be seeding thinks it has 0% of the file, and so it doesn't seed. Also I can see using the webui that the nodes do see each other as peers, just no one is seeding though one of them is supposed to. I realize this has become more of a qbittorent question, I posted it on their forums, but Im still hoping maybe one of you may know how to help me from here?

Comment: OK, so update:
 I am managing to seed and download the file in a different computer but though the directory and files all have the correct filenames there contents are being downloaded as unreadable gibrish. I tried  creating the torrent files with ctorrent and transmission and downloading using ctorrent and qtorrent and all have the same gibrish results.
I know it is a different issue now, and might require a different topic, but Im hoping you might have ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is embarrassing, I might have had it working for a while now, but I did change my implementation since I started. I just re-checked and the files I was transferring were corrupted on one of my earlier tries and I have been using them since.

So to sum up this is what worked for me if anybody else ends up needing the same setup:
I create torrents using "transmission-create /path/to/file/or/directory/to/be/torrented -o /path/to/output/directory/output_file_name.torrent" (this is because qbittorrent-nox doesn't provide a tool that I could find to create torrents) 
I run the torrent on the computer with the actual files so it will seed using "qbittorrent-nox ~/path/to/torrent/file/name_of_file.torrent"
I copy the .torrent file to all nodes and run "qbittorrent-nox ~/path/to/torrent/file/name_of_file.torrent" to start downloading

qbittorrent settings I needed to configure:
In "Downloads" change "Save files to location" to the location of the data in the node that is going to be seeding #otherwise that node wont know it has the files specified in the torrent and wont seed them.

To avoid issues with the torrents sometimes starting as queued and requiring a "force resume". This doesn't appear to have fixed the problem 100% though

In "Speed" tab uncheck "Enable bandwidth management (uTP)"
               uncheck "Apply rate limit to uTP connections"
In "BitTorrent" tab uncheck "Torrent Queueing"

Thanks for all the help and Im sorry I hassled people for no reason from some point..

Answer (score 0):

> but the node thats supposed to be seeding thinks it has 0% of the file, and so it doesn't seed.

If you create a metadata file (`.torrent`) with tool A and then want to seed it with tool B then you need to point B to both the metadata and the data (the content files) itself.

> I know it is a different issue now, and might require a different topic, but Im hoping you might have ideas.

You should create a new question which will have more room for you to provide details.